# What are the default rules used by make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Even when I do not specify a `Makefile`, `make` has built in commands, such as:

```
$ ls
a.c
$ make a.o
cc    -c -o a.o a.c
$
```

Is there a way to know the exact list of built in commands? For example, I am expecting something like:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(AAA) $(BBB) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AAA) $(BBB) -c -o $@ $<

...
```

It looks like the first flag variable is `CFLAGS` for C and `CXXFLAGS` for C++, but I have no idea what the other flag variables are (`AAA` and `BBB` above).

Does `make` store the default rules in some configuration file? Or is it in make's source code?

I am using `GNU Make 4.3` on a Fedora Linux machine.

Comment: Run `make -p -f/dev/null`.  The `-p` option tells make to print its database of rules, and `-f/dev/null` tells make to read an empty makefile so that the only rules in the database are the built-in ones.  See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html

Comment: @MadScientist this is what I am looking for. If you would like, you can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: There is also [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).

Comment: Just note that the catalog of rules in the manual is not complete.  It's more reliable to ask make for its list.